# Find greatest fraction in an array

Tags: c++

I'm stuck with an exercise of my programming course. I actually do not want the code I want more of a hint.

I have an array of fractions and I need to find the greatest fraction in the array. Moreover I have a function decimal() which converts the fraction to decimal. My idea was like this:

```
struct fraction &greatestFraction(struct fraction fractionArray[], int arrayLength){
    double greatestValue = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (decimal(fractionArray[i]) > greastestValue) {
            greatestValue = i;
        }
    }
    return fractionArray[];
}
```

Convert the fraction to decimal but I have to return a struct. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Don't you want greatestValue = decimal(fractionArray[i]); ? And adding an index to store which fraction gave you this greatest (greatestind = i;) ?

Comment: There is `std::max_element` in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: You confound value and index at some point.

Comment: Decide first what data should be stored in `greatestValue`. In `if (decimal(fractionArray[i]) > greastestValue)` you seem to compare the fractions' values, but in `greatestValue = i;` you assign the fraction's index (i.e. a position in the array).

Comment: thanks for helping. I think I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct fraction& greatestFraction(struct fraction fractionArray[], int arrayLength)
{
    double greatestValue = decimal(fractionArray[0]);
    int    greatestValueIndex = 0;

    for (int i=1; i<arrayLength; i++)
    {
        double value = decimal(fractionArray[i]);
        if (greastestValue < value)
        {
            greastestValue = value;
            greatestValueIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return fractionArray[greatestValueIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pick the first element as greatest value, because if all the elements are negative in the array, your soultion is wrong.

```
struct fraction &greatestFraction(struct fraction fractionArray[], int arrayLength){
    double greatestValue = fractionArray[0].numer / (double) fractionArray[0].denumer;
    size_t maxIndex = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
        double tmpVal = fractionArray[i].numer / (double) fractionArray[i].denumer;
        if (tmpVal > greatestValue) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return fractionArray[maxIndex];
}
```

If you need more accurate comparison, you can do something like that:

```
bool greater(struct fraction& a, struct fraction& b) {
    return a.numer * b.denumer > a.denumer * b.numer;
}

struct fraction &greatestFraction(struct fraction fractionArray[], int arrayLength){
    double greatestValue = fractionArray[0];
    size_t maxIndex = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
        if (greater(fractionArray[i], greatestValue)) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return fractionArray[maxIndex];
}
```